# replace string1 with string2 in many java files, only in comments

Tags: perl, intellij-idea, replace, read-eval-print-loop

I have around 3000 instance of replacement done in hundreds of files.   Replacing all occurance of **string1** with **string2** was easy.  IntelliJ allows me to replace all occurences in "comments and strings".

The  problem is that  the same string appear in comments and real code. I would like restrict the replacement only in comment section ( we use mix of /**/ or // )

Any library/IDE/script that can do this?

Comment: One half of the solution: [File::Comments::Plugin::Java](http://p3rl.org/File::Comments::Plugin::Java), [String::Comments::Extract](http://p3rl.org/String::Comments::Extract), [Regexp::Common::comment](http://p3rl.org/Regexp::Common::comment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
use Regexp::Common 'comment';
...
s/($RE{comment}{'C++'})/(my $x = $1) =~ s#string1#string2#g; $x/ge;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following regex to find all comments, and then replace what you want afterwards:

```
/(?>\/\*[^\*\/]*\*\/|\/\/([^\n])*\n)/
```

The first part `\/\*[^\*\/]*\*\/` Tries to find all `/**/` pairs where it finds something that starts with `/*` and then contains something other than end tag `*/` and the contains end tag */.

THe other part checks something that starts with `//` and goes to endline(`\n`) and contains something not newline between `([^\n]*)`.

Thus it should all comments