# How can I match and modify C and C++ comments with Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have the task of (trying to) do a search and replace within a large codebase for a word suffix, only when it occurs within comments. All of the comments are of the /* or // type but they are guaranteed to include most of the edge cases imaginable.

So I want to change this:

```
/* blah blah something__suffix blah */
```

to this:

```
/* blah blah something blah */
```

but I also want to change this:

```
// blah blah something__suffix blah
```

to this:

```
// blah blah something blah
```

And this:

```
/*
 * blah blah something__suffix blah 
 */
```

to this:

```
/*
 * blah blah something blah 
 */
```

And this:

```
/** 

// blah blah something__suffix blah 

*/
```

To this:

```
/** 

// blah blah something blah 

*/
```

ad nauseam (literally).

Initially I felt that this was a parser task and I installed cochinelle, and indeed it could parse my comments but it got stuck with my preprocessor macros and the workarounds seemed complex for someone who just has this as a one-off task. So now I'm considering regex.

I haven't found a lot of advice around about doing really robust search and replace within C and C++ comments with regex (besides "you need a parser"), but I did notice that there seems to be a pretty well road-tested perl script on the perl FAQ for removing comments in both of these styles [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#How-do-I-use-a-regular-expression-to-strip-C-style-comments-from-a-file?).

as follows:

```
$/ = undef;
$_ = <>;

s#/\*[^*]*\*+([^/*][^*]*\*+)*/|//([^\\]|[^\n][\n]?)*?\n|("(\\.|[^"\\])*"|'(\\.|[^'\\])*'|.[^/"'\\]*)#defined $3 ? $3 : ""#gse;

print;
```

My question: how to adapt this script so that instead of stripping the comment, the text that has been identified as a comment can then be searched for the suffix and the suffix removed, leaving the rest of the comment intact?

Comment: related: [replace string1 with string2, only in comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538466/replace-string1-with-string2-in-many-java-files-only-in-comments)

Comment: Note @daxim's link, the accepted answer there seems not to handle strings. So this expression is probably more robust.

Comment: That `Regexp::Common` is really great, didn't know it. Thanks daxim.

Comment: @Qtax Could you give an example of a string it doesn't handle?

Comment: @Halle, `x = "hello there /* oops this is not a comment */";`. The "comment" inside the string will be matched. While this expression handles strings properly.

Comment: Matching comment-bracketed non-comments inside strings would definitely be a dealbreaker for this script so the other approach doesn't look like it would apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it in two steps because you might have

```
/* foo__suffix bar__suffix */
```

First, extract the comment, then substitute any `__suffix` in the comment.

```
s{
   \G
   (?:(?!/[*/]).)*
   \K
   (   /[*] (?:(?![*]/).)* [*]/
   |   //   [^\n]*
   )
}{
   my $comment = $1;
   $comment =~ s/(?<=\w)__suffix//g;
   $comment
}xes;
```

---

Notes:

- `(?:(?!STRING).)` is to `(?:STRING)` as `[^CHAR]` is to `CHAR`.
- My solution will mess up if you have `//` or `/*` in a string literal.
- If you're ok with removing instances of `__suffix` that aren't preceded by an identifier, you can remove the `(?<=\w)`.
- If you're using 5.14 or higher, you can simplify

  ```
  s{...}{
     my $comment = $1;
     $comment =~ s/(?<=\w)__suffix//g;
     $comment
  }xes;
  ```

  to

  ```
  s{...}{
     $1 =~ s/(?<=\w)__suffix//rg
  }xes;
  ```

Comment: "My solution will mess up if you have // or /* in a string literal." That seems kind of probable in this case unfortunately.

Comment: Really? Well, changing `(?:(?!/[*/]).)*` to `(?: (?!/[*]|//|"). | "(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*" )*` would probably handle it well enough.

Comment: "Kind of probable" may be an overstatement, but "every time I've said that a weird case was unlikely to occur in this code I've had reason to regret it" isn't one :) . Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a good solution, but it works.

```
use strict; use warnings; use feature qw(say);
my @lines = (
qq~Example 1:
/* blah blah something__suffix blah */~,
qq~Example 2:
// blah blah something__suffix blah needs a newline at the end
~,
qq~Example 3:
/*
 * blah blah something__suffix blah 
 */~,
qq~Example 4:
/** 

// blah blah something__suffix blah 

*/~,
qq~Example 5 (string):
foobar '// blah blah something__suffix blah '~,
qq~Example 6:
public void main { return; } // this does__suffix nothing but needs newline
~,
);

foreach (@lines) {
  print "Before:\n$_\n";
  s!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/*][^*]*\*+)*/|//([^\\]|[^\n][\n]?)*?\n|("(\\.|[^"\\])*"|'(\\.|[^'\\])*'|.[^/"'\\]*)!
  { if (defined $3) { $3 } else { (my $temp = ${^MATCH}) =~ s/__suffix//; $temp;} } 
  !gsepx;

  print "After:\n$_\n\n";
}
```

It's probably not very efficient, but I don't think that is important for your job.

Comment: Using `$&` with this expression is wrong, as it matches more than just comments.

Comment: I didn't try to understand the expression, I just changed the substitution part. I guess you're referring to where the original said `#defined $3 ? $3 : ""#`. I'll have a look. Thanks.

Comment: Where is the use of $&? Yes, definitely no need for efficiency here.

Comment: `$&` is the same as `${^MATCH}`. The problem was that the regex also matches comments that are inside of quotation. I just changed that and updated the example. It should work now. Thanks for the tip, Qtax.

Comment: `$&` and `${^MATCH}` are not the same, although they are similar.